# asp.net don't work grid to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Simple program with a button '`btnExportToExcel`' when I click this button don't show any response.when I debug this button code after executing all lines shows the form after clicking button at second time cursor goes to another method named `GridView1_RowCreated`(used for designing grid) but don't response to convert grid to excel.

What should I do now?

```
 protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.ClearContent();           
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;
                                            filename=Inventory.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);


        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();

    }




  protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add CSS class on header row.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            e.Row.CssClass = "header";

        //Add CSS class on normal row.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
                  e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal)
            e.Row.CssClass = "normal";

        //Add CSS class on alternate row.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
                  e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
            e.Row.CssClass = "alternate";
    }
```

Comment: WHats on the wire? Install fiddler and see exactly what you are getting from the server. I have a feeling it is the HtmlTextWriter that is rendering the content as html not as a csv file. 
So figure out exactly what is happening on the wire through fiddler and post the response

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: This peace of code in content page when I remove UpdatePanel it works fine but I'm using UpdatePanel to avoid page refresh.Is there any process to avoid page refresh and also need grid to excel.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to Rebind the GridView on the post back.

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.ClearContent();           
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Inventory.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: It works without GridView1.DataBind() method that I mentioned in above.It works with just a gridview in another project for testing but when I'm trying to apply in working project It does't work whats happening I don't understand......Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

try this code working fine

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // Grid_bindExcel();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Category.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Label lblheader = new Label();
        lblheader.Font.Size = 14;
        lblheader.Font.Bold = true;
        lblheader.Text = "Category Detail";
        lblheader.RenderControl(hw);

        GrdExcel.Visible = true;
        GrdExcel.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        GrdExcel.Visible = false;
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```

Comment: After comment out  Grid_bindExcel() method works fine in a project with only contain a gridview but when I'm trying to apply in my working project it does't work.I don't understand what's the cause of this.......Thanks in advanced

Comment: comment Grid_bindExcel(); this method not requred you

Comment: Grid_bindExcel(); convert this method into GridView1.DataBind(); am I right or not.by using this method get the exception that's reason comment out it